# Can I create a Bitbucket wiki inside my project repository? (so both are pushed/pulled and editable from the IDE)

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, documentation, wiki

I'm thinking about creating documentation for a project, I want said documentation to go along said project (i.e. to be pushed, pulled along the code files). Bitbucket offers the wiki functionality, but it is stored on a different repository. Is there any way to have a Bitbucket wiki in the same repository as the project one, so both are pulled/pushed simultaneously?

Thanks in advance,
Iago

Comment: Bitbucket wikis live on bitbucket and are not apart of the repo.

Comment: But as BitBucket documentation says: "The wiki is a Git repository, so you can clone it and edit it like any other source files."

Comment: I stand corrected. You can nest a repo inside another by using [submodules](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule). I would recommend against this however.

Comment: Indeed, at the end I abandoned the nesting and used a multi-root project from the IDE